# Anyone know what Awe is?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have an assignment due for class and can find nothing about 'awe'?

The assignment says to create a script with a function called 'awe' that echo's the words "Because Linux is Awesome!" after 3 questions.

I'm very new to all this and would really like the help. I tried `awk` but from what I have seen in the videos I watched about this that this is not what he wants. Thanks.

Comment: The question tells you exactly what the instructor wants. Create a script. Add a function to the script. Call this function "awe". "Awe" does not exist, and will not exist, until you create it.

Comment: You don't need awk for asking questions, `echo` and `read` shell built ins will be enough for this assignment. Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Does that tell you how new I am to Linux, I have been looking for awe on every web-site possible. Thank you so very much, next time I will know that if I can't find it on a couple sites, just make it up.

Comment: Marci, you don't just Google the solution and copy-paste it somewhere. You learn principles, and create the solution yourself, only that way will make your education worth something (when you can apply these principles for some real-world shell script).

Comment: How would you feel if you were in a bus or a taxicab, the traffic light turned red, and the driver pulled out a computer and Googled “What do I do when the traffic light turns red?”  You go to school to *learn* information, not to get passing grades on your homework by turning around and asking somebody else for all the answers.

Comment: Although this should probably not actually be reopened in its current state, and the downvotes are reasonable, the reaction expressed in comments here is absurd. Some students unfortunately paste homework problems without applying effort, but that's not what has happened here. In this situation, the student *was unaware that user-defined shell functions existed at all* and assumed that there must be some existing facility called `awe`. Would you attack the professor for bad teaching, without knowing the details of *how* this misconception occurred? No? Then don't attack the student, either.

Comment: I cringe every time someone says they watched a *video* to learn a *command-line tool*...

Answer (score 11):

## Answer using the Bash shell:

> The assignment says to create a script with a function called 'awe' that echo's the words "Because Linux is Awesome!" after 3 questions.

The assignment says to create a function, so let's see what [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) tells us about [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions):

> Shell functions are a way to group commands for later execution using a single name for the group. They are executed just like a "regular" command. When the name of a shell function is used as a simple command name, the list of commands associated with that function name is executed. Shell functions are executed in the current shell context; no new process is created to interpret them.
>
> Functions are declared using this syntax:
>
> ```bash
> name () compound-command [ redirections ]
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```bash
> function name [()] compound-command [ redirections ]
> ```
>
> This defines a shell function named *name*. The reserved word `function` is optional. If the `function` reserved word is supplied, the parentheses are optional. The *body* of the function is the compound command *compound-command* (see [Compound Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands)). That command is usually a *list* enclosed between { and }, but may be any compound command listed above, with one exception: If the `function` reserved word is used, but the parentheses are not supplied, the braces are required. *compound-command* is executed whenever *name* is specified as the name of a command.

In short, a function is a set of commands bundled under a given name you supply, which is the name of the function.

The assignment tells you how the function shall be named (`awe`), as well as what this function shall do (output "Because Linux is Awesome!"). To output that message, you can use `echo`. The `echo` command, which Bash provides as a shell built-in, is used to output to [`stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (console). Given this information you can write your function:

```bash
awe(){
    echo "Because Linux is Awesome!"
}
```

Next in the assignment is to make it execute after having asked three questions. For this you can use the `read` command, which can accept several option flags. Let's see what the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) tells us [about `read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins):

> ```
> read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars]
>     [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name …]
> ```
>
> One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor *fd*
>   supplied as an argument to the `-u` option, split into words as described above in [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting), and the first word is assigned to the first *name*, the second word to the second *name*, and so on. If there are more words than names, the remaining words and their intervening delimiters are assigned to the last *name*. If there are fewer words read from the input stream than names, the remaining names are assigned empty values. The characters in the value of the `IFS` variable are used to split the line into words using the same rules the shell uses for expansion (described above in [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)). The backslash character ‘`\`’ may be used to remove any special meaning for the next character read and for line continuation. If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable `REPLY`.

`read` accepts several options. In this case, two are most relevant, since you want to ask the user a question and get input for them. Those options are:

> - `-r` → If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character. The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.
> - `-p prompt` → Display *prompt*, without a trailing newline, before attempting to read any input. The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a terminal.

While this is not the worst situation to forget `-r`, you almost always want to include it to prevent `\` from acting as an escape character. `-p` shows the user a prompt. You can put both options after a single `-`, so you might write something like this:

```bash
read -rp "Question? " variable
```

The user's input has been stored in `variable`. No we want to use that input, by including it in a sentence that we output back to the user. To expand `variable` into the value it holds, you put a `$` in front of it. This works even within double quotes.

```bash
echo "This is a reply to the user and it contains $variable!"
```

Normally this is all you need to solve this assignment. In my example script I added a little twist, to use a `if` condition to act upon whether "yes" or "no" was answered for the last question. So again lets see [what the manual tells us about `if` conditions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> The syntax of the `if` command is:
>
> ```bash
> if test-commands; then
>   consequent-commands;
> [elif more-test-commands; then
>   more-consequents;]
> [else alternate-consequents;]
> fi
> ```
>
> The *test-commands* list is executed, and if its return status is zero, the *consequent-commands* list is executed. If *test-commands* returns a non-zero status, each `elif` list is executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding *more-consequents* is executed and the command completes. If ‘`else alternate-consequents`’ is present, and the final command in the final `if` or `elif` clause has a non-zero exit status, then *alternate-consequents* is executed. The return status is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested true.

The `test-command` I have used in my example below is `[`, which is a shell built-in which tests for conditional true or false. When you use `[`, you must pass a final argument `]`. `=` tests variables for equality as strings.

So, here is the example script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# function 'awe' to output "Because Linux is Awesome!"
awe(){
    echo "Because Linux is Awesome!"
}

# asking three questions
read -rp "Enter your name!: " name
echo "Well, hello then $name!"
read -rp "How old are you?: " age
echo "Being $age makes you nearly as old as I am"
read -rp "Do you like Linux?: " likes_linux

# acting on if the last input is yes or something else in which case we assume no
if [ "$likes_linux" = "yes" ];then
    awe
else
    echo "Why don't you like Linux?"
fi
```

Comment: I have to wonder if people are downvoting this answer simply for its existence here. The direct reference to the manual provides OP and other new users the means to answer questions on their own, which is good for the site. I think a reference to the `man` and/or `apropos` commands might also be useful, taking context into account. The intermittent examples, explanations of rationale, and summaries of the manual quotes make this even more useful for the learner than a simple RTFM. In my opinion, this is an excellent answer, and I would upvote twice if I could.